# Hide Mobile Browser Address bar on full page scroll snap layout

Tags: html, css, angular

So I've been running into this annoying problem and I don't seem to be able to fix it by myself. I'm currently working on an experimental App written Angular (11.2).

The page itself should be divided into several screen filling sections which users scroll through as if it were specific tiles. Therefor, scroll snapping is a must.

However I'm simply not capable of hiding the mobile browser address bar. This is due to the fact that, in order to get the snapping effect, the page only consists of one single element that is scaled fitting the current viewport. Also manually hiding the browser address bar using the widely used `window.scrollTo(0,1)` hack does not work since there is no real scrolling to be achieved.

Thus my question
Can I somehow hide the browsers address bar while still being able to keep the required layout required for scroll snapping?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the app.manifest file to set your web-app to fullscreen. Dont know exactly if just works with installed pwas, bur you could give it a try.